# Select all rows and ignore the first row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm currently using the following SQL query which is returning 25 rows. How can I modify it to ignore the first row:

```
SELECT fiscal_year, SUM(total_sales) as sum_of_year, AVG(SUM(total_sales)) 
OVER () as avg_sum 
FROM sales_report 
GROUP BY fiscal_year 
ORDER BY fiscal_year ASC
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe LIMIT and OFFSET are available in SQL Server 2008. You will probably need to use some variant of ROW_NUMBER() (excluding where it equals 1).

Comment: ... _Why_ do you want to ignore the first row?  Why not just exclude that fiscal year with a `WHERE` clause?  Note that excluding it after the `AVG` has run (as with `OFFSET` or using a window function) would make the average 'incorrect' - you'd be adding numbers that aren't visible to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `EXCEPT` in SQL Server 2008.

```
SELECT fiscal_year, SUM(total_sales) as sum_of_year, AVG(SUM(total_sales)) 
OVER () as avg_sum 
FROM sales_report 
GROUP BY fiscal_year

EXCEPT

SELECT TOP 1 fiscal_year, SUM(total_sales) as sum_of_year, AVG(SUM(total_sales)) 
OVER () as avg_sum 
FROM sales_report 
GROUP BY fiscal_year 
ORDER BY fiscal_year ASC
```

For SQL Server 2012 and above, you can use `FETCH OFFSET`

Answer (score 1):

assuming this is exactly how you'd query it, then:

`SELECT fiscal_year, SUM(total_sales) as sum_of_year, AVG(SUM(total_sales)) OVER () as avg_sum 
FROM sales_report 
WHERE fiscal year <> (SELECT MIN(Fiscal_year) FROM sales_report))
GROUP BY fiscal_year 
ORDER BY fiscal_year ASC`

And then you can remove the "order by".
Works on all versions

Comment: ...this is probably the better option, but it will change his output compared to the other answers, because the running average would change.  Also, no, you (probably) can't remove the `ORDER BY` - if the OP wants them in a specific order (regardless of removing the 'first' one), he needs the clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` window function

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT Row_number()over(order by fiscal_year) as RN,fiscal_year, SUM(total_sales) as sum_of_year, AVG(SUM(total_sales)) 
OVER () as avg_sum 
FROM sales_report 
GROUP BY fiscal_year 
)
select * 
From cte
Where RN <> 1
ORDER BY fiscal_year ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is correct. This is what I have tried to make it:

```
SELECT fiscal_year
    ,a.sum_of_year
    ,AVG(SUM(a.sum_of_year)) OVER () AS avg_sum
FROM (
    SELECT Row_number() OVER (
            ORDER BY fiscal_year
            ) AS RN
        ,fiscal_year
        ,SUM(total_sales) AS sum_of_year
    FROM test_fiscal
    GROUP BY fiscal_year
    ) a
WHERE a.rN > 1
GROUP BY fiscal_year
    ,rn
    ,a.sum_of_year
ORDER BY fiscal_year ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

use to below query to build your query that works perfectly

```
WITH cte_customers AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
             ORDER BY 
                first_name, 
                last_name
        ) row_num, 
        customer_id, 
        first_name, 
        last_name
     FROM 
        sales.customers
) SELECT 
    customer_id, 
    first_name, 
    last_name
FROM 
    cte_customers
WHERE 
    row_num <> 1;
```